# FileMaker Pro UI Scripting

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I'm trying to import a script from one DB into another in FMP12 and found no other way then using UI scripting.
Most of the time the script stuck when I need to mark the checkbox, complaining that the UI element cannot be found, but as visible on the picture, it is referenced properly, at least this is how I see it:

Pls visit the link for the picture showing the problem, it is much clearer then if I write it down: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8c7xuazrb5cvlq/Screenshot_25_4_13_3_08_PM.jpg

The funny think is that sometimes the script works fine and I cannot figure out what is making it working fine sometimes.

Any idea what am I doing wrong, or if there is some other way to refer to that UI element?

Thanks
Zsolt

Comment: Try inserting a delay before the tell block.

Comment: Worked! I tested it few times and now it works every time. I hope it will stay like that. Thanks a lot. Obviously the delay is something to keep in mind when using UI scripting.